# How to Set Generated RowAction Template to sap.ui.table.TreeTable

Tags: sapui5

I would like to generate a [RowAction](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.table.RowAction) with JS dynamically in a surrounding `sap.ui.table.TreeTable`.

I would like to have a similar structure according to a (working) XML view as follows:

```
<t:TreeTable id="tree" rowActionCount="1">
    <t:columns>
        <t:Column>
            <t:label>
                <Label text="{i18n>ServicesTree_Name}"/>
            </t:label>
            <t:template>
                <Label text="{Description}" />
            </t:template>
        </t:Column>
    </t:columns>
    <t:rowActionTemplate>
        <t:RowAction>
            <t:RowActionItem 
            type="Delete"
            icon="sap-icon://delete"
            press=".onDelete" />
        </t:RowAction>
    </t:rowActionTemplate>
</t:TreeTable>
```

I have a controller which generates a RowAction with RowActionItem (see below code snippet), but how to put this into the TreeTable?

```
const oRowActionItem = new sap.ui.table.RowActionItem({
    type: sap.ui.table.RowActionType.Delete,
    icon: "sap-icon://delete"
});
const oRowAction = new sap.ui.table.RowAction();
oRowAction.addItem(oRowActionItem);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same as this [example from the Demo Kit](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.ui.table.sample.RowAction/code/Controller.controller.js), you can set the template via

```
this.byId("tree").setRowActionTemplate(/*generatedRowAction*/);
```

APIs such as [`setRowActionTemplate`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.table.Table/methods/setRowActionTemplate) are generated automatically by the ManagedObject from which all Controls derive. For each property and aggregation, an appropriate accessor and mutator are supplied.

More about generated APIs: https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject